# Unable to draw graphs with plot_ly function

Tags: r, r-plotly

Today I've been asked to draw some charts using plotly package for a Shiny application but i can't figure out how to solve my problem, so i've decided to ask for some help !

Everytime I try to use the function "plot_ly" I get the same error :

```
Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) :
Evaluation error: as_dictionary() is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use as_data_pronoun() instead.
```

I tried to remake the example from the official website of plotly and the result stay the same !

For instance, when i try the following code I get the message above :

```
library(plotly)

USPersonalExpenditure <- 
data.frame("Categorie"=rownames(USPersonalExpenditure), 
USPersonalExpenditure)
data <- USPersonalExpenditure[,c('Categorie', 'X1960')]

p <- plot_ly(data, labels = ~Categorie, values = ~X1960, type = 'pie')
```

I also re-installed the package, updated every package i had installed but their is nothing to do i'm still stucked with that error.

I didn't found anything revelant on google neither.

Thank you in advance and happy new year !

Comment: Hi César, welcome to SO and good work on solving your issue :) Could you include it as an answer rather than as an edit in your question? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue ! I didn't had the package dplyr installed actually...
The answer that helped me was given by *cderv* (https://community.rstudio.com/t/plotly-unable-to-draw-graphs/20639) :

> This seems like a compatibility issue between :package: version. rlang version seems to be newer than your installed dplyr can deal with